# What are the possible needs of more than 2 parameters of EventHandler(Object sender, CustomEvtArgs custEvtArgs)?

Tags: c#, events, generics, delegates, event-handling

I see the C# code when EventHandler has more than 2 parameter.

Is it a good practice?

What are the possible examples when implementing a custom event arguments CustomEvtArgs : EvtArgs class is not enough for dat of an event?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from creating more parameters. EventArgs derived classes are generally easier to maintain, because when you add a new parameter (eg: a new field to a SearchEventArgs type class), you don't have to rewrite all of your existing method calls, you can jut utilise the new parameter in new methods.

Comment: So, using more than 2 parameters is a bad practice?

Comment: It's personal style I guess. A lot of the BCL events tend to use EventArgs derived classes.

Comment: Using EventArgs derived class does not mean to have more than 2 parameters. Even more, I do not know how else it would have been possible to use EventArg without using derived class